# Enabling JSR-303 annotation validation in a service class (not in Spring controllers nor in JAX-RS resources)

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I'd like to use JSR-303 annotations for parameter validation of methods of a class other than a JAX-RS resources. Using the JEE containers it works on EJB/CDI beans, but I cannot get it running in Spring. The code might look like below.

Which maven dependency or other configuration am I missing? (I don't want to call the `Validator` myself. I want spring does the work for me here.)

**Note that the Person class is not a JPA entity, hence Hibernate Validator as the implementation of JPA cannot do the work here.**

```
public class Person{

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

}

@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl{

    public void create(@Valid Person person){
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you getting???

Comment: @JasonZ Here is the point when the firstName is null I don't get any error! I except to get a javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException which is not thrown.

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation of Spring you can inject validator to your service, look link http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html.

Example:

```
import javax.validation.Validator;

@Service
public class MyService {

@Autowired
private Validator validator;
```

Comment: As I described in my question, I don't want to use the validator explicitly because this is verbose and does not seem to be best practice to me. (In JAX-RS resources the same thing is done by Spring without the explicit use of Validator). Of course I can do this using AOP but that is my last "non-standard" Spring solution.

Comment: You can easily define validator for you controllers and use validator implicitly. But if you want to validate objects inside services, you need higher abstraction layer with reflection for services.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your last sentence?

Comment: I think injection of the Validator instance is as good as it gets in this case. The J2EE spec defines various integration points of Bean Validation with other frameworks, for example with JPA, JAX-RS, .... Outside of these defines integration points you need to call Validator yourself or write your own integration layer.

Comment: @Hardy it is kind of not very practical in Spring that you have to this stuff manually while on JEE CDI beans you can have the validation out of the box. I think I should then use AspectJ alongside with the Validator in order to have a solution like JEE. Thanks.